# android - Estorno de pagamento de app em alfa

Tags: android, google

Eu publiquei um *app* em alfa para teste de pagamento, e fiz o pagamento de um item integrado.
Como eu faço o reembolso e cancelo essa compra?

Answer (score 0):

Retirado, adaptado e traduzido da documentação oficial do Android:

> **Cancelamento de compras de teste concluídas**
>
> O Google Play acumula compras de teste concluídas para cada usuário, **mas não as passa para o processamento financeiro. Com o tempo, ele limpa automaticamente as compras cancelando-as.**
>
> Em alguns casos, você pode querer cancelar manualmente uma compra de teste para continuar os testes. Para o cancelamento de compras, você tem as seguintes opções:
>
> 1. **Aguarde as operações expirarem** - O Google Play limpa as compras de teste concluídas 14 dias após a data de compra.
> 2. **Cancelar as compras manualmente** - Você pode ir para o Centro de Pagamentos Google, ir para a transação, e depois cancelá-la. Você pode encontrar transações observando os seus números de pedido.
>
> Você também pode cancelar a assinatura para a realização de compras de teste para um app manualmente na Play Store, ou usar o método `cancel()`.
>
> Importante: Os métodos `refund()` e `revoke()` não suportam compras de testes.

**Link original:** [Testing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)